# php bind data explanation (possibly kohana specific?)

Tags: php, kohana, bind

Attempting to dive in to Kohana and I'm reading the Unofficial 3.0 Kohana wiki as it's more user friendly than the user docs atm imo.

It mentions "Binding Data to a View", like so:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Welcome extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $about_page = View::factory('pages/about')
                            ->bind('title', $title)
                            ->bind('header', $header);

        $title='This is my title';
        $title='This is my header';
        $this->request->response = $about_page;
    }

} // End Welcome
```

Which outputs:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>This is my title</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>This is my header</h1> 
</body> 
</html>
```

How is this possible? Or what's this method/process called?
The variables are set after they are "used", if you like, hence my confusion.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called passing by reference. See more at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php.

Comment: thanks for the link, will look in to it. Does this bear any relevance to the term "late binding"?

Comment: If you mean 'late static binding', then no, that has to do with `self` & `static` keywords in static methods of classes. The 'binding' they speak of there is binding at compile time in the PHP engine, not in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this when doing research on kohana framework.

Check this link, shadowhand puts it in very basic terms: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/5038/views-difference-between-assign-bind-and-set/p1

This answer wasn't to help original person, it was to save someone time if they're getting stuck ;)